# Given a fixed average speed in the speed vs. distance graph, is it the fastest to travel constantly at that speed?

Tags: kinematics, speed, distance

Is it true that among all the ways to travel a distance $X$ with an average speed $E$ in the speed vs. distance graph, traveling with a constant speed $E$ minimizes the time it takes to complete the travel?
If yes, then is there any other way to travel for which it also takes that minimal time to complete the travel?

Note that I'm not talking about average speed (i.e. total distance divided by total time). What I mean by "an average speed $E$ in the speed vs. distance traveled so far graph" is that $E$ is equal to the average of the function $f: \text{distance} \to \text{speed}$, i.e. $f(x)$ is the speed of the object when the total distance it has traveled is $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, traveling at constant speed is the unique way that minimizes travel time. I do hope there is an easier way to show this, but this is the best I can do at the moment.

The problem is the following: find the function $f(x)$ that minimizes
$$T = \int\limits_0^X{\frac{dt}{dx}dx} = \int\limits_0^X{\frac{1}{f(x)}dx},$$
subject to the constraint
$$EX=\int\limits_0^Xf(x)dx. $$

Let's transform this into an equivalent problem that is a bit simpler: define
$$g(x) = f(x)-E.$$
Then, we must find the function $g(x)$ that minimizes
$$T=\frac{1}{E}\int\limits_0^X{\frac{dx}{1+g(x)/E}}$$
subject to
$$0=\int\limits_0^Xg(x)dx.$$

Note the equality:
$$\frac{1}{1+z}=1 - z +\frac{z^2}{1+z},$$
you can verify this by simplifying the right hand side. Substituting this in the integral for $T$,
$$T=\frac{1}{E}\left[\int\limits_0^X{dx} - \int\limits_0^X{\frac{g(x)}{E}}dx + \int\limits_0^X{\frac{g^2(x)/E^2}{1+g(x)/E}}dx \right].$$
The second integral is zero by the constraint equation, so
$$T = \frac{X}{E}+\frac{1}{E}\int\limits_0^X{\frac{g^2(x)/E^2}{1+g(x)/E}}dx.$$
Note that as long as $g(x)>-E$ (you don't stop or change direction), the second term is always non-negative, and it is zero only when $g(x)=0$ (assuming it is a continuous function). Therefore, $g(x)=0$ (or $f(x)=E$) minimizes $T$ with the constraint that the "average" speed is $E$.

Comment: I edited my question to explain what I mean by average speed.

Comment: @avraham I will update my answer. Are you familiar with calculus of variations or the method of Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: I'm familiar with neither of them.

Comment: @avraham See the updated answer.

Comment: I understood everything apart from how you got to the first integral that is equal to T.

Comment: @avraham I've added one more equation to clarify it. It comes from the fact that the time it takes to travel a small distance $\delta x$ is equal to $\delta x$ divided by the velocity $f(x)$. The total time is the sum of these small time increments, hence the integral.

Comment: Is there a simple way to prove that travels(with an "average" speed E, over a distance X) that have complete stops take more time than going constantly at E(over a distance X)? (Your proof doesn't consider the travels in which for some x, f(x)=0.)

Comment: Probably, but not with this method, at least not without modifications, since the time integral is no good in this case. I don't think it would be difficult though, once have the result in my answer. It should appeal to your common sense that stopping for any amount of time won't get you to your destination any faster, you could use this as a starting point.